# Why my props action doesn't work in an "if" statement in "onClick", but it works outside the "if" statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-props

This code works:

```
<button onClick={props.action}>
     Sign in
</button>
```

This code doesn't work:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" onClick={() => logIn(username, password).then((res) => res.data===0 ? props.action : console.log(res.data) )}>
        Sign in
</button>
```

I'm new to reactjs
Does any body know why it doesn't work in the second way?

Comment: I think you have to change `props.action` to `props.action()`, please add your entire component code for the full answer. Also, look at this please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a tip; Make a function and then call the funciton onClick instead. The code gets simpler to read!

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work because `.then` is only used in promises and your function is not a promise. First you have to declare the promise then you can use it in props, hope it helps to solve your problem.